# Remove 'u' suffix in an output coming from an API call

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am using an API call to get an output and I am appending it to a text file. But for one of the parameter coming from the output (json) it is getting suffixed by 'u'. I am unable to remove this

I tried using

```py
tags = str(nameout.json()["tags"])
```

but it still appends u into the text file

```py
tags="[u'tomcat', u'app', u'all', u'subt', u'biz', u'sub1t']"
```

I want the output without 'u' suffixed in it. New to python, any help would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: It is not a suffix, but a prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nameout.json()` is suposedly json response, already parsed into python JSON object.

`nameout.json()["tags"]` will return the list object with tags. You really don't want to convert it to `str` in the first place.

`u` prefix just indicate that these are unicode. You don't need to remove them. They are not printed when you print the list elements properly, e.g.:

```
tags = [u'tomcat', u'app', u'all', u'subt', u'biz', u'sub1t']
print(', '.join(tags))
for tag in tags:
    print(tag)
```

output:

```
tomcat, app, all, subt, biz, sub1t
tomcat
app
all
subt
biz
sub1t
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it was indeed already pulling a list. Also if possible can you tell me what happens here? when you use this join tags?

Comment: these are just two different ways (out of many) to print the content of list. for the use of `str.join()` check https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Answer (score 0):

```
tags = eval(tags) # Will give you a list
```

In order to convert it to a string:

```
tags = str(eval(tags))
```

> UPDATE

This might be dangerous approach as the data might be untrusted and might contain some malicious code:
The best would be to iterate the data and join in a string:
`', '.join(tags) # Considering tags is a list of string`

Comment: This is very dangerous, and probably won't even work. OP has mentioned that they are receiving this data from the other end of a JSON API, meaning that it should be treated as untrusted. If the API sent back the JSON structure `{"tags": "import os; os.system('bad stuff')"}` then bad stuff will happen. It also may not fix OP's problem, depending on python version. OP wants the `u`s removed, but calling `str` on a list of unicode objects in python 2.7 keeps them there: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69Eo7ikSCO1LDFHQym6VD0tP189VklTU8HWVgGJ//8/AA.

Comment: Very true. If the data is from a 3rd party then this is not the way it should be followed. The best way would be : `', '.join(tags)`